# No radio signals with antenna

Tags: frequency, antenna, radio

I have an antenna I made with about 2 feet of insulated copper wire, stripped at one end.  The antenna is connected to the positive side of a 1000uF capacitor, using [this](http://puu.sh/6ZhnD.png) circuit.  I am using a 741 op-amp.  The negative voltage for it comes from a separate battery with its positive lead connected to ground, and its negative lead connected to the op-amp.  When I test the voltage of the output of this op-amp, it is constant.  It has no frequency.  This leads me to believe that my antenna has absolutely no signals coming from it.  How can I fix my antenna?

I am also using a silicon diode.

Comment: Are you trying to make an AM radio? If so you'll need a tuned circuit of some form to get any sensible output.

Comment: The goal is to get any output at all.  After that I will build a resonator.  For now though, I'm not even getting static.

Comment: In your attached circuit, what gain are you expecting from the opamp, and why? When you say you get "no frequency", is the opamp outputting a value near one of its power rails? Do you have split-rail supplies for the opamp? What voltage are you powering it with?

Comment: (Note that if you do succeed in building this system, the most likely thing you'll pick up is the 50Hz mains hum)

Answer (score 1):

I tried following your link, but there was nothing there. So my advice can only be very general.
1:  741 opamps are only good to about 20KHz, depending on how much gain you have (more gain = less bandwidth). While there are a few Low Frequency (LF) stations, you'd be better off using a different amplifier.
2: Opamps like the 741 use a "split rail". You need a positive supply, **and** a negative supply, **and** zero volts (or ground).
3: A capacitor on its own is not enough - you need a tuned circuit. Hopefully, this was on your missing circuit diagram. You need a coil and a tuning capacitor, in parallel. Adjusting the capacitor tunes the radio. As written, the only thing you **might** hear is electric noise generated by a thunderstorm.